# Is the layout for a vertical panel with components correct?

Tags: uibinder

How to insert a vertical panel in the form for laying out the components in a vertical layout fashion.

For example as 
   Component 1
   Component 2
   Component 3.

Please give me an example code.
I want to fit it in the following fashion!
[Display of the panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVjkW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HorizontalPanel mainPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

VerticalPanel leftSidePanel = new VerticalPanel();
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();

leftSidePanel.addMember(textBox1);
leftSidePanel.addMember(textBox2);

VerticalPanel rightSidePanel = new VerticalPanel();
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.addItem("value1","value1");
listBox.addItem("value2","value2");

rigthSidePanel.addMember(listBox);

mainPanel.addMember(leftSidePanel);
mainPanel.addMember(rightSidePanel);
```